# Does end to end encryption have applications/use cases outside of messaging/email?

Tags: encryption

I was reading up on end to end encryption and I mostly found applications in messaging (Whatsapp, Telegram etc) and well, email (PGP (sort of?)).

I am curious to know if there are applications for End to end encryption beyond these. Say, communication between two processes in a distributed system? Not sure if they really need end to end encryption.

Comment: HTTPS is end-to-end encryption too (i.e. web browser to web server). And this is probably much more used than messaging and email together.

Comment: To be fair, E2EE usually refers to the communication between (end) users of a system, not client-server communication.

Comment: @Arminius: In case of accessing content on a web server the server is the intended endpoint of the communication and thus HTTPS provides end-to-end encryption. Contrary to this in a web based chat system where the server has access the messages in clear the server is not the intended endpoint and thus it is not end-to-end encryption. In other words: TLS (and also HTTPS) can be used to provide end-to-end encryption but this does not mean that all TLS is end-to-end. Similar not all PGP is end-to-end, for example if company wide encryption gateways are used.

Comment: All good encryption technology is end to end. What most people mean when they say end to end is really just whether the ends are actually where you think they would be.

Comment: @LieRyan Not necessarily. Cloudflare does not provide end-to-end encryption from the perspective of the server and client, for example. Nor does an IRC private message between two people, even if the server uses TLS. When it actually _ends_ is where the endpoint is. A temporary stop is not the end, even if the encryption "ends" there.

Comment: @LieRyan: To add to the comment from forest: use of TLS both in SMTP (mail) and in SIP (VoIP) is hop-by-hop and not end-to-end, i.e. every MTA or SIP proxy in between has read and write access to the plain message.

Comment: I agree, but from the perspective of IRC/SMTP/SIP server operator, TLS as used there are end-to-end, the user's end to their service's end. Of course, for the user of these services, they probably don't see it that way. Cloudflare can be considered end to end if the server operator considers Cloudflare as part of your service provider (i.e. not less trusted than your web hosting provider). Terminating SSL at your PaaS/IaaS provider can be considered end to end, or not, depending on whether you see these service providers as your end or just a minimally trusted third party you use.

Comment: My point is that in most applications, there's not really a clear cut distinction between end to end and not end to end encryption. It depends on where you sit and what you consider in your threat model. Even PGP emails are not necessarily clearly end to end, if you send a PGP encrypted email to your friend's assistant so the assistant can print your message for your friend to read, then your PGP encrypted email isn't really encrypted end to end to its final destination.

Comment: essentially anything that uses encryption on the application layer will be E2E. If you upload a password protected zip backup to something like dropbox, that's E2E, no matter what the providers are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think just asking for use cases of end-to-end encryption is a very broad question. But in general: whenever two parties exchange sensitive information which need to be protected against sniffing (and probably also modification) by a third party end-to-end encryption makes sense. This includes for example direct messaging, mail communication, protecting passwords entered into web sites, protecting your online banking, telephony, accessing a remote desktop, management of a remote device in the context of IoT and many many more.

You should also note what end-to-end *encryption* does not offer. While (almost?) all end-to-end encryption implementations protect the message against modification they often don't provide the assurance that the sender is the claimed one or that no message are lost or that messages got replayed. But these are often requirements you have in end-to-end scenarios and which then need to be provided by additional techniques, like cryptographic signatures or message counters.

And then there are cases where end-to-end encryption does not provide the protection one might hope. For example, if you have two processes on the same machine and owned by the same user then end-to-end encryption probably does not make much sense. It does not protect against a user with same or higher privileges since this user could ptrace the applications to extract the unencrypted data from there. For this scenario a communication using (properly protected) UNIX domain sockets or use of socketpair or pipe offers the same protection but without the overhead of encryption.

Comment: "Almost" all is correct. SSHv1 supported using a CRC for message integrity, allowing spoofed messages. The IRC end-to-end encryption protocol FiSH is fairly popular but uses ECB by default (though plain CBC is also supported). It is vulnerable to replay attacks as well. Duplicity does end-to-end backups but can be configured not to cryptographically sign the backups. I'm sure there are plenty more.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer! I had been going with the colloquial use of E2E so did not think of SSL as an end to end scheme. Can you expand a bit on "protecting your online banking" ?

Comment: @Limit: When doing online banking within a browser hopefully HTTPS is used and the endpoint of the connection is the bank, which is the expected endpoint for the user. Any information entered (password, TAN.. whatever is used) is protected end-to-end

Comment: Thanks! I thought there was something other than HTTPS that you were talking about so asked

Answer (score 3):

Some examples of end to end encryption that aren't messaging:

1. Cloud based password manager where all cryptography are on the client side, and the server is designed to be an untrusted party
2. Cloud file storage/sync/backup where all encryption are done in the client side, and the server is designed to be an untrusted party
3. A command and control server hosted on the hacker's basement running as a Tor Hidden Service

Answer (score 0):

- Yes, PGP is usually e2e.
- Cloud storage is rolling out e2e, see Nextcloud.
- Backups are sometimes done e2e.
- Websites, as mentioned above, seem like they are e2e from the server to the client so they cannot be read by the coffee shop WiFi.

The last example illustrates that some things seem like they are e2e but according to the [wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-to-end_encryption) and what seems like common usage to me e2e is between users or their devices. Otherwise essentially all encrypted communication qualifies as e2e between the encrypting parties. So a connection to a webserver would normally not be considered e2e. Nor would communication between distributed systems. Of course the term still makes sense and might well be used. It's not a standard in any way.

Comment: "*Cloud storage is rolling out e2e*" That's overly broad. That a few open source "private cloud" (i.e. just a server) software packages are doing e2e, doesn't mean that cloud storage in general is moving in that direction. I see it as a big shortcoming that they're not, so I'd try to avoid creating this impression.

Comment: @Luc I agree that's why I wanted to point out that there is now almost an option that does e2e. ;)